# Hardware error while burning DVD

Tags: windows-7, dvd-burning, nero

I have Windows 7 and a Sony Vaio VPCSA but I never could write a DVD. I can write a CD but when I try to write a DVD with Nero it just fails with a hardware error. I bought new blank DVD+R and still the same error. I try with another program to burn an ISO file and still I get hardware error.

[image: Screenshot from Free ISO Burner]

[image: Screenshot from imgburn]

What can be done? The log from Nero is

```
Windows 7 6.1
AMD64
Wow64Process
Nero Version: 12.0.20.0
Internal Version: 12,0,20,0

Recorder:             <MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ242AS> Version: 1.40 - HA 1 TA 0 - 12.0.20.0
 Adapter driver:      <Serial ATA>              HA 1
 Drive buffer  :      2048kB
 Bus Type      :      via Inquiry data
CD-ROM:               <ELBY     CLONEDRIVE      >Version: 1.4  - HA 1 TA 1 - 12.0.20.0
 Adapter driver:      <SCSI>                    HA 1

=== Scsi-Device-Map ===
DiskPeripheral       : Volume0                         iaStor Port 0 ID 0  DMA: On 
CdRomPeripheral      : MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ242AS         iaStor Port 0 ID 1  DMA: Off
CdRomPeripheral      : ELBY    CLONEDRIVE      1.4     VClone Port 1 ID 0  DMA: Off

=== CDRom-Device-Map ===
MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ242AS    D:   CdRom0
ELBY CLONEDRIVE            E:   CdRom1
=======================

AutoRun : 1
Excluded drive IDs: 
WriteBufferSize: 83886080 (0) Byte
BUFE           : 0
Physical memory     : 4095MB (4194303kB)
Free physical memory: 4095MB (4194303kB)
Memory in use       : 27 %
Uncached PFiles: 0x0
Global Bus Type: default (0)
Check supported media : Disabled (0) 

4.6.2013
UDF compilation
14:14:44    #1 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 464
    LockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL

14:14:44    #2 Text 0 File Isodoc.cpp, Line 7610
    UDF document burn settings
    ------------------------------------------
    Determine maximum speed : FALSE
    Simulate                : FALSE
    Write                   : TRUE
    Finalize CD             : TRUE
    Multisession            : FALSE
    Burning mode            : DAO
    Mode                    : 1
    UDF Mode                : pure
    UDF Options             : automatic
    UDF Revision            : 1.02
    UDF Partition Type      : physical

14:14:44    #3 PHASE 214 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2066
    Generation of disc structures started

14:14:44    #4 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 10675
    ---- Disc Structure: Physical Format Information of Control Data Zone in the Lead-in (10h) ----
    Media Type: 0, Layer: 0, Address: 0 (0 h), AGID: 0; Length: 2050
     Book Type: DVD-R (2), Part Version: 2.0x (5), Extended Part Version: 2.1 (33)
     Disc Size: 120 mm,      Maximum Transfer Rate: <not specified> (F h)
     Number of Layers: 1,    Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP),  Layer Type: recordable
     Linear Density:         0,267 um/bit,  Track Density:  0,74 um/track
     Starting Physical Sector Number of Data Area: 30000 h (DVD-ROM, DVD-R/-RW, DVD+R/+RW)
     Outer Limit of Data Recordable Area:          26127F h
     Data in Burst Cutting Area (BCA) does not exist
      Revision number of maximum recording speed: 6.0
      Revision number of minimum recording speed: -
      Revision number table of recording speed: 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 - - 
      Class: 0,  Extended part version: 33
      Start PSN of the Extra Border Zone: 2FE10 h
      Start PSN of Physical format information blocks in Extra Border Zone: 2FFA0 h
     Media Specific [16..783]:
        00 60 00 10 20 30 40 50 - 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 00    .`...0@P...!....
        00 02 FE 10 00 02 FF A0 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
       01 40 C1 FD 9E D8 52 00 - 02 84 0D 12 98 99 90 00    .@....R.........
        03 43 4D 43 20 4D 41 00 - 04 47 2E 20 41 4D 33 00    .CMC.MA..G..AM3.
        05 88 80 00 00 00 02 00 - 06 09 0D 14 98 88 90 00    ................
        07 88 80 00 00 00 00 00 - 08 07 17 0A 0E 09 04 00    ................
        09 95 07 0D 0B 88 88 00 - 0A 80 00 00 00 00 10 00    ................
        0B 06 17 15 B8 99 85 00 - 0C B8 9A 32 03 20 32 00    ...........2..2.
        0D 00 00 D0 00 00 00 00 - 0E 09 1F 39 2F 25 1C 00    ...........9/%..
        0F 50 19 29 19 89 B5 00 - 10 88 84 00 04 00 04 00    .P.)............
        11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 12 09 2B 37 2D 29 1B 00    ..........+7-)..
        13 50 1D 2D 1F A6 B5 00 - 14 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .P.-............
        15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 16 0B 45 3D 3B 1F 25 00    ..........E=;.%.
        17 30 25 31 0D 8A B5 00 - 18 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .0%1............
        19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 1A 0C 51 51 51 45 2D 00    ..........QQQE-.
        1B 90 23 2D 19 79 B5 00 - 1C 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    ..#-.y..........
        1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

14:14:44    #5 Text 0 File compose.cpp, Line 969
    GenUDF2: 1 transfer items prepared.

14:14:44    #6 PHASE 215 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2066
    Generation of disc structures completed

14:14:44    #7 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 3605
    Turn on Disc-At-Once, using CD-R/RW, DVD R/RW, DVD DL, DVD-RAM, BD-R/RE, BD DL media

14:14:45    #8 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 10675
    ---- Disc Structure: Physical Format Information of Control Data Zone in the Lead-in (10h) ----
    Media Type: 0, Layer: 0, Address: 0 (0 h), AGID: 0; Length: 2050
     Book Type: DVD-R (2), Part Version: 2.0x (5), Extended Part Version: 2.1 (33)
     Disc Size: 120 mm,      Maximum Transfer Rate: <not specified> (F h)
     Number of Layers: 1,    Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP),  Layer Type: recordable
     Linear Density:         0,267 um/bit,  Track Density:  0,74 um/track
     Starting Physical Sector Number of Data Area: 30000 h (DVD-ROM, DVD-R/-RW, DVD+R/+RW)
     Outer Limit of Data Recordable Area:          26127F h
     Data in Burst Cutting Area (BCA) does not exist
      Revision number of maximum recording speed: 6.0
      Revision number of minimum recording speed: -
      Revision number table of recording speed: 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 - - 
      Class: 0,  Extended part version: 33
      Start PSN of the Extra Border Zone: 2FE10 h
      Start PSN of Physical format information blocks in Extra Border Zone: 2FFA0 h
     Media Specific [16..783]:
        00 60 00 10 20 30 40 50 - 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 00    .`...0@P...!....
        00 02 FE 10 00 02 FF A0 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        01 40 C1 FD 9E D8 52 00 - 02 84 0D 12 98 99 90 00    .@....R.........
        03 43 4D 43 20 4D 41 00 - 04 47 2E 20 41 4D 33 00    .CMC.MA..G..AM3.
        05 88 80 00 00 00 02 00 - 06 09 0D 14 98 88 90 00    ................
        07 88 80 00 00 00 00 00 - 08 07 17 0A 0E 09 04 00    ................
        09 95 07 0D 0B 88 88 00 - 0A 80 00 00 00 00 10 00    ................
        0B 06 17 15 B8 99 85 00 - 0C B8 9A 32 03 20 32 00    ...........2..2.
        0D 00 00 D0 00 00 00 00 - 0E 09 1F 39 2F 25 1C 00    ...........9/%..
        0F 50 19 29 19 89 B5 00 - 10 88 84 00 04 00 04 00    .P.)............
        11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 12 09 2B 37 2D 29 1B 00    ..........+7-)..
        13 50 1D 2D 1F A6 B5 00 - 14 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .P.-............
        15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 16 0B 45 3D 3B 1F 25 00    ..........E=;.%.
        17 30 25 31 0D 8A B5 00 - 18 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .0%1............
        19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 1A 0C 51 51 51 45 2D 00    ..........QQQE-.
        1B 90 23 2D 19 79 B5 00 - 1C 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    ..#-.y..........
        1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

14:14:45    #9 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 334
    [D: BD-MLT UJ242AS  ] Last possible write address on media:  2298495
    Last address to be written:             442303

14:14:45    #10 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 346
    [D: BD-MLT UJ242AS  ] Write in overburning mode: NO (enabled: CD)

14:14:45    #11 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 3034
    Recorder: MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ242AS, Media type: DVD-R
     Disc Manufacturer ID: <CMC MA> <G. AM3>
     Disc Application Code: 64, Disc Physical Code: 193

14:14:45    #12 Text 0 File DlgWaitCD.cpp, Line 537
    [D: BD-MLT UJ242AS  ] >>> Protocol of DlgWaitCD activities: <<<
    =========================================

14:14:45    #13 Text 0 File ThreadedTransferInterface.cpp, Line 878
    Setup items (after recorder preparation)
     0: TRM_DATA_MODE1 ()
        2 indices, index0 (150) not provided
        original disc pos #0 + 442304 (442304) = #442304/98:17.29
        relocatable, disc pos for caching/writing not required/ required
        -> TRM_DATA_MODE1, 2048, config 0, wanted index0 0 blocks, length 442304 blocks [D: MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ242AS]
    --------------------------------------------------------------

14:14:45    #14 Text 0 File ThreadedTransferInterface.cpp, Line 1094
    Prepare [D: MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ242AS] for write in CUE-sheet-DAO
    DAO infos:
    ==========
     MCN: ""
     TOCType: 0x00; Session Closed, disc fixated
     Tracks 1 to 1:                                  Idx 0         Idx 1      Next Trk
       1: TRM_DATA_MODE1, 2048/0x00, FilePos             0             0     905838592, ISRC ""
    DAO layout:
    ===========
     ___Start_|____Track_|_Idx_|_CtrlAdr_|_____Size_|______NWA_|_RecDep__________
            0 |  lead-in |   0 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00
            0 |        1 |   0 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00
            0 |        1 |   1 |    0x41 |   442304 |        0 | 0x00
       442304 | lead-out |   1 |    0x41 |        0 |        0 | 0x00
    MediaType: DVD-R

14:14:45    #15 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 251
    SPTILockVolume - completed successfully for FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME

14:14:45    #16 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 4467
    Caching options: cache CDRom or Network-Yes, small files-No (<64KB)

14:14:45    #17 PHASE 24 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2066
    Caching of files started

14:14:45    #18 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 4589
    Cache writing successful.

14:14:45    #19 PHASE 25 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2066
    Caching of files completed

14:14:45    #20 PHASE 36 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2066
    Burn process started at 2x (2,770 KB/s)

14:14:45    #21 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 10675
    ---- Disc Structure: Physical Format Information of Control Data Zone in the Lead-in (10h) ----
    Media Type: 0, Layer: 0, Address: 0 (0 h), AGID: 0; Length: 2050
     Book Type: DVD-R (2), Part Version: 2.0x (5), Extended Part Version: 2.1 (33)
     Disc Size: 120 mm,      Maximum Transfer Rate: <not specified> (F h)
     Number of Layers: 1,    Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP),  Layer Type: recordable
     Linear Density:         0,267 um/bit,  Track Density:  0,74 um/track
     Starting Physical Sector Number of Data Area: 30000 h (DVD-ROM, DVD-R/-RW, DVD+R/+RW)
     Outer Limit of Data Recordable Area:          26127F h
     Data in Burst Cutting Area (BCA) does not exist
      Revision number of maximum recording speed: 6.0
      Revision number of minimum recording speed: -
      Revision number table of recording speed: 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 - - 
      Class: 0,  Extended part version: 33
      Start PSN of the Extra Border Zone: 2FE10 h
      Start PSN of Physical format information blocks in Extra Border Zone: 2FFA0 h
     Media Specific [16..783]:
        00 60 00 10 20 30 40 50 - 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 00    .`...0@P...!....
        00 02 FE 10 00 02 FF A0 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
      01 40 C1 FD 9E D8 52 00 - 02 84 0D 12 98 99 90 00    .@....R.........
        03 43 4D 43 20 4D 41 00 - 04 47 2E 20 41 4D 33 00    .CMC.MA..G..AM3.
        05 88 80 00 00 00 02 00 - 06 09 0D 14 98 88 90 00    ................
        07 88 80 00 00 00 00 00 - 08 07 17 0A 0E 09 04 00    ................
        09 95 07 0D 0B 88 88 00 - 0A 80 00 00 00 00 10 00    ................
        0B 06 17 15 B8 99 85 00 - 0C B8 9A 32 03 20 32 00    ...........2..2.
        0D 00 00 D0 00 00 00 00 - 0E 09 1F 39 2F 25 1C 00    ...........9/%..
        0F 50 19 29 19 89 B5 00 - 10 88 84 00 04 00 04 00    .P.)............
        11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 12 09 2B 37 2D 29 1B 00    ..........+7-)..
        13 50 1D 2D 1F A6 B5 00 - 14 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .P.-............
        15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 16 0B 45 3D 3B 1F 25 00    ..........E=;.%.
        17 30 25 31 0D 8A B5 00 - 18 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .0%1............
        19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 1A 0C 51 51 51 45 2D 00    ..........QQQE-.
        1B 90 23 2D 19 79 B5 00 - 1C 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    ..#-.y..........
        1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

14:14:45    #22 Text 0 File ThreadedTransferInterface.cpp, Line 2924
    Verifying disc position of item 0 (relocatable, disc pos, no patch infos, orig at #0): write at #0

14:14:45    #23 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 10675
    ---- Disc Structure: Physical Format Information of Control Data Zone in the Lead-in (10h) ----
    Media Type: 0, Layer: 0, Address: 0 (0 h), AGID: 0; Length: 2050
     Book Type: DVD-R (2), Part Version: 2.0x (5), Extended Part Version: 2.1 (33)
     Disc Size: 120 mm,      Maximum Transfer Rate: <not specified> (F h)
     Number of Layers: 1,    Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP),  Layer Type: recordable
     Linear Density:         0,267 um/bit,  Track Density:  0,74 um/track
     Starting Physical Sector Number of Data Area: 30000 h (DVD-ROM, DVD-R/-RW, DVD+R/+RW)
     Outer Limit of Data Recordable Area:          26127F h
     Data in Burst Cutting Area (BCA) does not exist
      Revision number of maximum recording speed: 6.0
      Revision number of minimum recording speed: -
      Revision number table of recording speed: 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 - - 
      Class: 0,  Extended part version: 33
      Start PSN of the Extra Border Zone: 2FE10 h
      Start PSN of Physical format information blocks in Extra Border Zone: 2FFA0 h
     Media Specific [16..783]:
        00 60 00 10 20 30 40 50 - 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 00    .`...0@P...!....
        00 02 FE 10 00 02 FF A0 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        01 40 C1 FD 9E D8 52 00 - 02 84 0D 12 98 99 90 00    .@....R.........
        03 43 4D 43 20 4D 41 00 - 04 47 2E 20 41 4D 33 00    .CMC.MA..G..AM3.
        05 88 80 00 00 00 02 00 - 06 09 0D 14 98 88 90 00    ................
        07 88 80 00 00 00 00 00 - 08 07 17 0A 0E 09 04 00    ................
        09 95 07 0D 0B 88 88 00 - 0A 80 00 00 00 00 10 00    ................
        0B 06 17 15 B8 99 85 00 - 0C B8 9A 32 03 20 32 00    ...........2..2.
        0D 00 00 D0 00 00 00 00 - 0E 09 1F 39 2F 25 1C 00    ...........9/%..
        0F 50 19 29 19 89 B5 00 - 10 88 84 00 04 00 04 00    .P.)............
        11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 12 09 2B 37 2D 29 1B 00    ..........+7-)..
        13 50 1D 2D 1F A6 B5 00 - 14 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .P.-............
        15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 16 0B 45 3D 3B 1F 25 00    ..........E=;.%.
        17 30 25 31 0D 8A B5 00 - 18 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .0%1............
        19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 1A 0C 51 51 51 45 2D 00    ..........QQQE-.
        1B 90 23 2D 19 79 B5 00 - 1C 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    ..#-.y..........
        1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

14:14:45    #24 Text 0 File DVDR.cpp, Line 3135
    Recording mode: Sequential Recording Mode

14:14:45    #25 Text 0 File DVDR.cpp, Line 3293
    Start write address at LBA 0
    DVD high compatibility mode: Yes

14:14:45    #26 SPTI -1066 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 224
    CdRom0: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1066)
    CDB Data:   0xAC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 00 
    Sense Key:  0x05 (KEY_ILLEGAL_REQUEST)
    Sense Code: 0x24
    Sense Qual: 0x00
    Sense Area: 0x70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 24 
    Buffer x0c8dd480: Len x648

14:14:45    #27 SPTI -1066 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 224
    CdRom0: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1066)
    CDB Data:   0xAC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 00 
    Sense Key:  0x05 (KEY_ILLEGAL_REQUEST)
    Sense Code: 0x24
    Sense Qual: 0x00
    Sense Area: 0x70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 24 
    Buffer x0c8dd480: Len x648

14:14:45    #28 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 10675
    ---- Disc Structure: Physical Format Information (00h) ----
    Media Type: 0, Layer: 0, Address: 0 (0 h), AGID: 0; Length: 2050
     Book Type: DVD-R (2), Part Version: 2.0x (5), Extended Part Version: 2.1 (33)
     Disc Size: 120 mm,      Maximum Transfer Rate: <not specified> (F h)
     Number of Layers: 1,    Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP),  Layer Type: recordable
     Linear Density:         0,267 um/bit,  Track Density:  0,74 um/track
     Starting Physical Sector Number of Data Area: 30000 h (DVD-ROM, DVD-R/-RW, DVD+R/+RW)
     Outer Limit of Data Recordable Area:          30000 h
     Data in Burst Cutting Area (BCA) does not exist
      Revision number of maximum recording speed: 6.0
      Revision number of minimum recording speed: -
      Revision number table of recording speed: 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 - - 
      Class: 0,  Extended part version: 33
      Start PSN of the Extra Border Zone: 0 h
      Start PSN of Physical format information blocks in Extra Border Zone: 0 h
     Media Specific [16..783]:
        00 60 00 10 20 30 40 50 - 00 00 00 21 00 00 00 00    .`...0@P...!....
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        01 40 C1 FD 9E D8 52 00 - 02 84 0D 12 98 99 90 00    .@....R.........
        03 43 4D 43 20 4D 41 00 - 04 47 2E 20 41 4D 33 00    .CMC.MA..G..AM3.
        05 88 80 00 00 00 02 00 - 06 09 0D 14 98 88 90 00    ................
        07 88 80 00 00 00 00 00 - 08 07 17 0A 0E 09 04 00    ................
        09 95 07 0D 0B 88 88 00 - 0A 80 00 00 00 00 10 00    ................
        0B 06 17 15 B8 99 85 00 - 0C B8 9A 32 03 20 32 00    ...........2..2.
        0D 00 00 D0 00 00 00 00 - 0E 09 1F 39 2F 25 1C 00    ...........9/%..
        0F 50 19 29 19 89 B5 00 - 10 88 84 00 04 00 04 00    .P.)............
        11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 12 09 2B 37 2D 29 1B 00    ..........+7-)..
        13 50 1D 2D 1F A6 B5 00 - 14 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .P.-............
        15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 16 0B 45 3D 3B 1F 25 00    ..........E=;.%.
        17 30 25 31 0D 8A B5 00 - 18 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    .0%1............
        19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 1A 0C 51 51 51 45 2D 00    ..........QQQE-.
        1B 90 23 2D 19 79 B5 00 - 1C 88 80 00 00 00 00 00    ..#-.y..........
        1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

14:14:48    #29 Text 0 File DVDR.cpp, Line 3435
    Reserved Track size: 442304 (6BFC0h, 863MB) -> return code 0

14:14:48    #30 Text 0 File CUDFTransferItem2.cpp, Line 712

    GenUDF2 FS Layout:
    =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
        Sectors to be written: 442304
                Session Start: Sector 0
             Volume Structure: Sector [0, 256] (257 Sectors)
                    Meta Data: Sector [257, 1589] (1333 Sectors)
                         Data: Sector [1590, 442004] (440415 Sectors)
                   After Data: Sector [442005, 442015] (11 Sectors)
                Trailer Track: Sector [442016, 442303] (288 Sectors)

    GenUDF2 Parameters:
    =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
                     PrepTime: 06-04-2013 14:14:44
                 UDF Revision: 1.02
           UDF Partition Type: Physical
             UDF Special Mode: None
             Bytes per Sector: 2048
                Session Start: 0
     Physical Partition Start: -1
               Total Capacity: 2298496
           Multi Session Mode: None
                    Disc Type: DVD-R
                     OS Class: 0
                    Volume ID: New
         Allow Unicode Labels: 0
          Duplicate Meta Data: 1
                 MS Info File: 00000000
            VMS Rollback File: 00000000
            Create ISO bridge: 0
             ECC Block Length: 16
        Sparing Packet Length: 32
         Allocation Unit Size: 32
          Alignment Unit Size: 16
                Make Writable: 0
                  Access Type: Read-only

14:14:48    #31 Text 0 File ThreadedTransfer.cpp, Line 273
    Pipe memory size 83836800

14:14:53    #32 SPTI -1106 File SCSIPassThrough.cpp, Line 224
    CdRom0: SCSIStatus(x02) WinError(0) NeroError(-1106)
    CDB Data:   0x2A 00 00 00 02 A0 00 00 20 00 00 00 
    Sense Key:  0x03 (KEY_MEDIUM_ERROR)
    Sense Code: 0x73
    Sense Qual: 0x03
    Sense Area: 0xF1 00 03 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 1C 23 73 03 
    Buffer x10600580: Len x10000
    0x05 01 02 00 86 00 01 00 0E 1F B0 00 9F 01 00 00 
    0x00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 
    0x00 00 01 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF A5 14 00 00 

14:14:53    #33 TRANSFER -60 File ThreadedTransfer.cpp, Line 1233

14:14:53    #34 CDR -1106 File Writer.cpp, Line 339
    Power calibration error
    D: MATSHITA BD-MLT UJ242AS

14:14:53    #35 PHASE 181 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2066
    Writing lead-out...

14:14:53    #36 Text 0 File DVDR.cpp, Line 3748
    EndDAO: Last written address was 671 (29Fh)

14:14:53    #37 Text 0 File DVDPlusDualLayer.cpp, Line 1462
    SetDriveCaps: Set LAST LBA of layer 1 to 0

14:14:53    #38 PHASE 38 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2066
    Burn process failed at 2x (2,770 KB/s)

14:14:53    #39 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 301
    SPTIDismountVolume - completed successfully for FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME

14:14:53    #40 Text 0 File Cdrdrv.cpp, Line 12127
    DriveLocker: UnLockVolume completed

14:14:53    #41 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 464
    UnLockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL
```

Comment: Is it Dell or Sony Vaio? Which model?

Comment: Could you burn DVDs before this issue? Or is this the first time it has occurred? Based on the model, it looks like the drive supports DVD+R.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I updated the question with the relevant answers to your questions, the model name and what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you tell us how many programs installed on your laptop to burn the DVD's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How To Fix "Power Calibration Error" While Burning CD/DVD](http://www.megaleecher.net/Fix_Power_Calibration_Error) :

> Their could be several possible reasons and solutions for the above
>   error, basically what is happening is for some reason the CD/DVD
>   burning software is unable to determine the Optimum Power Calibration
>   rate (a small pre-burn test to determine optimal laser power for
>   writing), resulting a disk burn failure. There is no easy way to
>   pinpoint the exact reason, so try all the possible fixes from top to
>   bottom (easy to hard) and see what works:

- Try using different brands of quality blank media, most common reason
  for such errors is cheap blank media
- Try burning at lower speeds (Highly effective)
- Disable IMAPI Service (Works in most cases)
- Try updating or changing your CD\DVD burning software to the latest version
- Try upgrading your writer's firmware
- Clean your burner laser lens by blowing real hard into the device,
  or by using a cleaner CD, or get it cleaned by a professional.
- Change to a higher-quality burner

Answer (score 1):

You may need to get DVD-R disks.  Check the specs on your DVD drive and find out if it can burn both - and + DVDs.  It may only take the -R.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to burn this DVD using lower speed and see if that helps. And what DVD brand you are using ?

May be this [link](http://www.megaleecher.net/Fix_Power_Calibration_Error) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case getting some rubbing alcohol and few cotton swabs did the job, remember it burns and may leave some residue behind so soak the tip in alcohol and use only one head for soaking the other to dry and perform this on any laptop reader burner and it will work again. I recommend cleaning every 5 to 10 burns